# Writing into Range.FormulaArray gives me a #NAME! error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Nothing really fancy here, altough I need to split the formula in 2 because it is longer than 255 characters (sources: http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213181).

```
    f1 = "=SI(1=1,SOMME(SI(mySheet!$R:$R = ""something"",SI(mySheet!$AQ:$AQ = AM$1, NBCAR(Incidents!$AP:$AP)-NBCAR(SUBSTITUE(mySheet!$AP:$AP,$B2,"""")))))/NBCAR($B2)-X_X_X())"
    f2 = "SOMME(SI(mySheet!$R:$R = """",SI(mySheet!$AQ:$AQ = AM$1, SI(mySheet!$AM:$AM = $A2,SI(DROITE(mySheet!$AP:$AP,6) = $B2,1))))),"""""
    .Range("AM2").FormulaArray = f1
    .Range("AM2").Replace "X_X_X()", f2
```

The formulas are in French, which shouldn't really matter. The formula is correctly returned in the cell AM2, so here is the result:

```
={SOMME(SI(1=1;SI(mySheet!$R:$R = "something";SI(mySheet!$AQ:$AQ = AM$1; NBCAR(mySheet!$AP:$AP)-NBCAR(SUBSTITUE(mySheet!$AP:$AP;$B2;"")))))/NBCAR($B2)-SOMME(SI(mySheet!$R:$R = "something";SI(mySheet!$AQ:$AQ = AM$1; SI(mySheet!$AM:$AM = $A2;SI(DROITE(mySheet!$AP:$AP;6) = $B2;1)))));"")}
```

However, I get a #NAME! error. If I look into the formula debug, the error comes from my first function, Excel isn't able to interpret `SI()` (which is the French for `IF()`). I tried completely removing that `IF()` clause but then Excel can't interpret the first function which is now `SOMME()` (`SUM()`).

If I just click into the formula bar and press CTRL+Shift+Enter (not changing anything), it returns the correct value.

Why doesn't Excel give me the right number after VBA sets the array formula? Why does it work if I just *resubmit* the formula in Excel? And why is it always having trouble with the first function? I guess there is some other kind of limitation that I am not aware of.

I found another similar issue while browsing the Web but no solution.

Comment: Because Excel has `.Formula` for formulas in English and `.FormulaLocal` for formulas in the language of the Excel interface. You need the local version, but there isn't one for arrays. You have to provide array formulas in English. You could e.g. set this French formula to `.FormulaLocal` of a temporary (hidden) range, then read back `.Formula` from the same range and set that as `.FormulaArray` on the desired range. But you shouldn't, because your code won't work on any Excel version other than French.

Comment: I tried using the English function names in .FormulaArray but Excel doesn't like it either. It doesn't really matter much if it doesn't work on non-French versions of Excel since we are in a business workgroup and there is no English version of Office anyway.

Comment: Nevermind, it works with the English names. Wow. Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Excel has `.Formula` for formulas in English and `.FormulaLocal` for formulas in the language of the Excel interface.

You need the local version, but there isn't one for arrays. You have to provide array formulas in English.

You could e.g. set this French formula to `.FormulaLocal` of a temporary (hidden) range, then read back `.Formula` from the same range and set that as `.FormulaArray` on the desired range. But you shouldn't, because your code won't work on any Excel version other than French. The most portable thing is to always use English formulas in your code.