# How to combine FormulaArray and FormulaLocal options in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am sending functions inside VBA code to the cells with a VBA-code line like below:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").FormulaLocal = "=somefunctions_in_local_language"
```

I am using `FormulaLocal` option because the functions in cells are in the local language, not in English.

Now I want to send array functions, and I am supposed to use `FormulaArray` to do this. However, even the array functions will be in the local language. I guess I am supposed to combine both `FormulaArray` and `FormulaLocal` somehow, but how?

I tried to find if there is something like `FormulaArrayLocal`, but there is not such a thing. So any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing into Range.FormulaArray gives me a #NAME! error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250756/writing-into-range-formulaarray-gives-me-a-name-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link didn't give a direct answer, but I did find a solution:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").FormulaLocal = "=somefunctions_in_local_language"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").FormulaArray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Formula
```

It should only be `.Formula` in the second line. If you use `.FormulaLocal`, then you get an error.

Comment: Nice one! Come back in 48 hours to accept this as the answer.

Comment: What error did you get when you used `.FormulaLocal`?

Comment: @IronMan I will try to translate from the local language. The error message is something like `Run-time error '1004'. Unable to set FormulaArray property for the Range class`

Comment: OK, now I did find the reason of that `Run-time error '1004'` for `FormulaArray` property. The `FormulaArray` property can not process more than 255 characters which is explained in the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213181