# FormulaArray throws an error with correct array formula

Tags: vba, excel

`MyData.Columns("R").Address` is `$R$10:$R$121`
`AddressCurr` is `$D$10:$D$121`
`AddressPr` is `$O$10:$O$121`
`MyData.Columns(5).Address` is `$E$10:$E$121`

```
AddressPr = MyData.Columns("O").Address
AddressCurr = MyData.Columns("D").Address
MyData.Columns("R").FormulaArray _
    = "=IF(" & AddressCurr & ">0;1;0)"
```

Third line throws:
*Run-time error '1004' Unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class*

Whenever I input formula `=IF($D$10:$D$121>0,1,0)` on a sheet manualy, it works as intended.

**Why does Run-time error keeps popping out when populating range with correct array formula?**

Note: This formula is a part of a bigger one `=ROUND($O$10:$O$121/IF($D$10:$D$121=0,1,$D$10:$D$121)*$E$10:$E$121,-1)`

```
MyData.Columns("R").FormulaArray _
    = "=" & AddressPr & "/" & _
            "IF(" & AddressCurr & "=0,1," & AddressCurr & ")*" & _
            "" & MyData.Columns(5).Address & ""
```

It throws an error as well.

On the contrary following formula works like a charm:

```
MyData.Columns("R").FormulaArray _
    = "=" & AddressPr & "/" & _
        "" & AddressCurr & "*" & _
        "" & MyData.Columns(5).Address & ""
```

My guess is that it can't form a boolean array, but following doesn't work with `ROUND` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
MyData.Columns("R").FormulaArray = "=IF(" & AddressCurr & ">0;1;0)"
```

to

```
MyData.Columns("R").FormulaArray = "=IF(" & AddressCurr & ">0,1,0)"
```

In VBA you should use `,` as a separator even if you have different separator in your Excel.

Additionaly, please note that in VBA you should use English formula names and not your local ones when using .Formula or .FormulaArray.

If you would like to use your local language formulas you could use .FormulaLocal however, it does not seem that there is array version of .FormulaLocal (indirect solution: [How to combine FormulaArray and FormulaLocal options in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435662/how-to-combine-formulaarray-and-formulalocal-options-in-excel-vba)). Please notice that using .FormulaLocal requires you to use  your local separator.

Comment: I used russian formulas, just pretend that all **;** you find are actualy **,** ^^'. My formulas actualy look something like this `"=ЕСЛИ(" & АдресТекущий & ">0;1;0)"`

Comment: Changing that makes code work flawlessly for me. In VBA you should use English formula names like you did ("IF") and "," as a formula separator (I have Polish excel and ";" as seprator in excel as well :) )

Comment: You should change an answer to your comment and I will accept it, I just used english formulas and it worked, formula separators weren't an issue in the end.

Comment: [@tomjohnriddle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5627791/tomjohnriddle) is right. When you use VBA, your formulas must be in English. If you want to use your language formulas, check the property `FormulaLocal`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns +1 I would use `FormulaLocal` but I needed an array formula.