# #Name? error in cells with VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I am running a MonteCarlo Simulation in Excel with VBA but I only receive `#Name?` errors in the respective cells. When I click into one of these cells, press `F2` and then `Return` the error disappears and the value is properly calculated. What is wrong here?

This is the code line calculating the respective value:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Start_Rate * EXP(NORM.S.INV(RAND())* Standard_Deviation * (" & i & " ^1/2)) "
```

And that is the entire code (if necessary):

```
Sub MC_Simulation()

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim start_row As Integer
Dim start_column As Integer

iterations = Worksheets("Run_MC").Range("MC_Simulations").Value
Duration = Worksheets("Run_MC").Range("Duration").Value
Mean = Worksheets("Run_MC").Range("Mean").Value
Start_Rate = Worksheets("Run_MC").Range("Start_Rate").Value
Standard_Deviation = Worksheets("Run_MC").Range("Standard_Deviation").Value

start_row = 15
start_column = 1

For i = 1 To Duration
    For k = 1 To iterations

    Worksheets("Run_MC").Cells(start_row, start_column + i).Select
    Selection.Value = i
    Worksheets("Run_MC").Cells(start_row + k, start_column).Select
    Selection.Value = k
    Worksheets("Run_MC").Cells(start_row + k, start_column + i).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Start_Rate * EXP(NORM.S.INV(RAND())* Standard_Deviation * (" & i & " ^1/2)) "
    'Selection.Value

    Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If it works from the formula bar and does not work from the code, you have a localized version of Excel and should either [use `FormulaLocal`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26625383/11683) from code or [provide the formula in English](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25251099/11683).

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the VBA variables out of the quotations:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Start_Rate & "*EXP(NORM.S.INV(RAND())*" & Standard_Deviation & "*(" & i & "^1/2))"
```

Comment: `Start_Rate` and `Standard_Deviation` are defined as named ranges. It should work as is.