# Inserting long array formula with VBA doesn't work even after splitting the formula into parts to get around the 250-character limit

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill in an array formula into a cell with VBA. My formula is over 250 characters, so I've split it into six parts which are less than that. However, anytime I run the code I still get the "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class" error.

The relevant lines:

```
Dim Formulapart1 As String
Dim Formulapart2 As String
Dim Formulapart3 As String
Dim Formulapart4 As String
Dim Formulapart5 As String
Dim Formulapart6 As String

Formulapart1 = "=INDEX(11111;MATCH(1;($A$1=22222)*(G$1=33333)*($S$5=44444);0);MATCH($S$2;55555;0))"
Formulapart2 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$a$1:$u$22788"
Formulapart3 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$Q$1:$Q$22788"
Formulapart4 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$H$1:$H$22788"
Formulapart5 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$M$1:$M$22788"
Formulapart6 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$1:$U$1"

With wb.Worksheets(1).Range("G4")
    .FormulaArray = Formulapart1
    .Replace "11111", Formulapart2
    .Replace "22222", Formulapart3
    .Replace "33333", Formulapart4
    .Replace "44444", Formulapart5
    .Replace "55555", Formulapart6
End With
```

To reiterate, I just want to paste the formula into cell G4, and can't figure out why this isn't working. I've read through multiple discussions and articles on the topic and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `FormulaArray` accepts formulas [in English](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251099/11683). In your particular case it would be enough to replace the `;`s with `,`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated by @GSerg, `FormulaArray` only accepts **english** style formulas. 
So change the line with this one and it will work (I tested on my Excel):

```
Formulapart1 = "=INDEX(11111,MATCH(1,($A$1=22222)*(G$1=33333)*($S$5=44444),0),MATCH($S$2,55555,0))"
```

For convenience, here's the full modified code:

```
Dim Formulapart1 As String
Dim Formulapart2 As String
Dim Formulapart3 As String
Dim Formulapart4 As String
Dim Formulapart5 As String
Dim Formulapart6 As String

Formulapart1 = "=INDEX(11111,MATCH(1,($A$1=22222)*(G$1=33333)*($S$5=44444),0),MATCH($S$2,55555,0))"
Formulapart2 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$a$1:$u$22788"
Formulapart3 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$Q$1:$Q$22788"
Formulapart4 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$H$1:$H$22788"
Formulapart5 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$M$1:$M$22788"
Formulapart6 = "'\\common-fs-01\supervisors\resource optimization\resourcing tables 2019\[queries_all_v2.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$1:$U$1"

With wb.Worksheets(1).Range("G4")
    .FormulaArray = Formulapart1
    .Replace "11111", Formulapart2
    .Replace "22222", Formulapart3
    .Replace "33333", Formulapart4
    .Replace "44444", Formulapart5
    .Replace "55555", Formulapart6
End With
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh god so it was that easy. I got it to work now with the modified code. Thanks a million guys, you're lifesavers!

Comment: You're welcome! If you found this answer useful, please accept it. Thank you!